# jQuery post and .NET MVC action - returning partial results to end user

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question in regards to a concept that I haven't had a chance to encounter before, but I have been thinking about it for a long time and I wanted to see if it's doable in .NET MVC 5 using jQuery...

So let's say we have an action  in controller which looks like this:

```
[ActionName("OurTestAction")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OurTestAction()
{
 Method1();
//returning some sort of "signal" here to client side to notify that the method1 finished processing data.. ?
 Method2();
 Method3();
 return Json("Ok");
}
```

Where the action was triggered like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.post("/Controller/OurTestAction").done(function(response){
// displaying the result here
});
}):
```

So the idea that I had with this piece of code is that I could be able to tell end user when was the Method1() called and ended it's life cycle. Once the Method1(); finishes what it was supposed to do, I'd like to be able to tell the end user in his browser something like this (via jQuery): Method1() finished processing the data , moving onto the method2();

Is something like this doable with jQuery and .NET, and if so how?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: It's not as simple as you're suggesting in the example, but it's certainly possible.  Take a look at a tool called SignalR.  Its purpose is to maintain a web sockets connection whereby the server-side code can "push" messages to client-side code.  There are a variety of examples, from simple messaging notifications to chat systems.

Comment: No. You can't return multiple responses from your controller via a single post. One possible solution would be to move your different methods into their own controller actions and then call those in sync from your JS code. Another possible approach would be to open up a websocket connection and return your responses that way, but that might be overkill.

Comment: its possible by making Method1(),Method2() and Method3() separate and  make Async false

Comment: @Dilip could you show me an example of that  ? :)

Comment: @mituw16 yes I agree.. The reason why I'm asking for this is because i'm making long requests to my end api with bunch of parameters, so the request can sometimes take 1-1.5 minutes... and I'd like to be able to tell the end user what's happening in the meantime while they wait ...

Comment: function Method1 () {
    
        PostToServer({
            url: "url of method 1",
            data: {  },
            async : false,
            onSuccess: function (result) {
               if (!result.isValid) {
                  alert(error in method 1);
                }
            else {
               Method2();
            }
        }, onError: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error in method 1);
        }
    });
}

function Method2 () { 
same code like function 1
}

Comment: Then, websockets are what you're looking for (SignalR is a library for handling websocket connections, server-side). HTTP follows a request-response model. Each request has one and only one response. Websockets provide a way to allow two-way client-server communication (on top of HTTP), such that a server can send a response without first having received a request. This then allows you to do things like update the client with the server progress without the client having to issue a request for the latest status.

Comment: Also, FWIW, anything that isn't near instantaneous should not actually be being handled by your web application. Instead, you should offload it to a background process (which might even be on a different server). You can then employ websockets to check on the progress of the task in that other process. To the user it all looks the same, but you then have a much reduced chance of deadlocking your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Break your controller methods into different actions.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method1()
{
  Method1();
  return Json("Ok");
}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method2()
{
  Method2();
  return Json("Ok");
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method3()
{
  Method3();
  return Json("Ok");
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'controller/method1'
}).done(function(resp) {
   //do stuff to notify users method 1 is complete
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'controller/method2'
    }).done(function(resp2) {
        //do stuff to notify users method 2 is complete
    });
});
```